# Neo4j + JavaEE + Java 7 + Glassfish + Netbeans 8.0 CONFIGURATION

Tags: jakarta-ee, neo4j, glassfish, netbeans-8, session-bean

I need a project that use all this. I can't connect Neo4j in Server Mode with JavaEE on Glassfish. 
Only in Embedded mode.
I use https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc specifications.
The Error is:

> **
>
> Advertencia:   Unable to start the Restlet java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to create SSLContext.  at
>   org.restlet.ext.httpclient.HttpClientHelper.configure(HttpClientHelper.java:277)
>     at
>   org.restlet.ext.httpclient.HttpClientHelper.start(HttpClientHelper.java:478)
>     at org.restlet.Client.start(Client.java:217)    at
>   org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:315)  at
>   org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:177)    at
>   org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1136)
>     at
>   org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleOutbound(ClientResource.java:1225)
>     at
>   org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1068)
>     at
>   org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1044)
>     at
>   org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:950)
>     at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.get(ClientResource.java:658)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.rest.Resources$DiscoveryClientResource.readInformation(Resources.java:143)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.rest.Resources.getDiscoveryResource(Resources.java:61)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.Neo4jConnection.createExecutor(Neo4jConnection.java:109)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.Neo4jConnection.(Neo4jConnection.java:79)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.Connections$4.doCreate(Connections.java:65)
>     at org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.Connections.create(Connections.java:80)
>     at org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:80)    at
>   org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:42)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)  at
>   otrasclases.NeoServer.raiz(NeoServer.java:40)     at
>   otrasclases.OtroMainNoLoToquen.main(OtroMainNoLoToquen.java:13)   at
>   managebeans.mbPrueba.mb(mbPrueba.java:55)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)   at
>   javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:136)    at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)    at
>   com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.filedownload.FileDownloadActionListener.processAction(FileDownloadActionListener.java:55)
>     at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was
>   incorrect     at
>   sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:772)
>     at
>   sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
>     at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1433)  at
>   org.restlet.ext.ssl.DefaultSslContextFactory.createSslContext(DefaultSslContextFactory.java:317)
>     at
>   org.restlet.ext.httpclient.HttpClientHelper.configure(HttpClientHelper.java:274)
>     ... 73 more Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException:
>   Password verification failed  at
>   sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:770)
>     ... 77 more
>
> **

My SessionBeans is:

```
@Override
public int raiz() throws Exception {   
  if (raiz != -1) {      
   return raiz;
  } else {    
    Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/");
    try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("MATCH (n) WHERE NOT (n)<-[:FATHER]-() RETURN n.accession");
        rs.next();
        this.setRaiz(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("n.accession")));
    }
    return raiz;
  }
}
```

**

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/");
```

Here run fail.

Answer (score 1):

This error (Unable to create SSL context) usually relates to a bad certificate that you have in place.  I don't think it's related to glassfish or neo4j.

[See this thread for more information](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.restlet/15974).

In essence, you need to make sure that you have a valid SSL cert set up for your server here, or otherwise configure restlet to ignore that.